# Swagger - What must JSON syntax be to satisfy @ApiModelProperty of type Map<String, String> with Grails deployment

Tags: json, grails, swagger

When I have an endpoint defined with one of the parameters like this:

```
@ApiModelProperty(value = 'Some parameters', required = false)
Map<String, String> someParams
```

What must the JSON syntax be to satisfy an endpoint request?

Does not seem like this work:

```
{
    "body": {
        "body": "Some text."
    },
    "someParams": {
        "someKey": "someValue"
    }
}
```

Comment: `{ "someParams": { "someKey": "someValue" } }` Doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, will edit my question to show more of my JSON request, that was just an extraction.